# WPF MessageBox in App.xaml.cs stops MainWindow initialisation so app never appears but is (apparently) running correctly

Tags: wpf

There's no error message and no indication why it is not displaying the window. The app initialises App.xaml.cs: `App() {}` and I can step through the App.xaml file. It gets the startup uri and then... silence. No output in the Output window and no unhandled exception and no window, I can't find where to put a breakpoint to debug as it isn't hitting the start of MainWindow.xaml.cs.

Really confused. 
This was working 20m ago.

In that time all I did was add Windows.Office.Interop.Outlook reference. I removed the reference and rebuilt but still the same. Would that cause this problem? Has anyone seen this before? Google isn't helping!

**EDIT :**

`App.xaml.cs`:

```
public App()
{
    using (var dbContext = new DBEntities())
    {
        if (!db.Exists())
        {
            try
            {
                db.Database.Create();
                MessageBox.Show("Database created"); // this is the problem!!
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've added App.xaml.cs, I found that the problem was using a MessageBox to give info (this is still in development!). I'd been meaning to get rid of it and eventually did and my problem went away. This meant I could find relevent Goolge results:
[MSDN query and answer for exactly my problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fea3d1c2-990e-4973-bb1c-03db83f58c61/wpf-app-never-appears-if-showing-a-messagebox-during-app-constructor?forum=wpf)

I will be adding an 'loading window' in between app load and main window load eventually in which I will be able to feedback information using Bindings etc.

Comment: Share your code. `App.xaml` and `App.xaml.cs` please.

Comment: App.xaml.cs included, in doing so - I figured out the problem and have also included that in the question. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed error by removing the `MessageBox.Show(..)` call. The selected answer from the [MSDN URL](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fea3d1c2-990e-4973-bb1c-03db83f58c61/wpf-app-never-appears-if-showing-a-messagebox-during-app-constructor?forum=wpf) given in the question states:

> "I performed a test based on your description, the applicationi stop at the method : USER32!GetMessageW+0x33, calling USER32!NtUserGetMessage"

I assume this is what was occurring in my case, although I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you create a new window and set that as the StartupUri?
You also might want to create a new project and make sure that the namespaces referenced in the App.xaml in your existing app haven't somehow been inadvertently edited.

Comment: I found that changing the StartupUri to a completely new, fresh and blank window didn't help and other WPF projects were still loading ok - in the end I found it was because I was showing a MessageBox in the App.xaml.cs constructor which then paused the app load, it wasn't going wrong, hence the lack of exception!